# How common is it for countries to draft directly from prison?

Tags: russian-federation, comparative-politics, prison, conscription

[According to RFERL](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-drafting-prisoners-law-ukraine-war-attrition/32627429.html)

> Russian legislation currently forbids the military to register convicted prisoners for the draft or call them up for duty. But last month, the Defense Ministry submitted a proposal to remove that restriction from the law, potentially making tens of thousands of convicts fair game for deployment to Ukraine. [...]
>
> Russia currently has 266,000 convicts behind bars, Deputy Justice Minister Vsevolod Vukolov said October 4. The overwhelming majority are men.

However, the piece doesn't say how common or uncommon this practice might be elsewhere, i.e. do countries that have a draft normally draft from prisoners as well, or do they normally rely on "coaxing" for the latter (i.e. promising to reduce sentences etc.) as Russia has done insofar?

Comment: Just anecdotal, but as I see it most militaries prize loyalty and some semblance of honor, qualities criminals generally lack. Criminal convictions are usually disqualifying for drafts or enlistments, because it's assumed that convicts will have difficulty with discipline and obedience. There are exceptions like the French Foreign Legion, where convicts are given an opportunity to wipe the slate clean through service elsewhere, but convicts rarely find their way into regular military ranks.

Comment: Frankly, I think it's a sign of desperation: a need for cannon fodder. I expect any drafted prisoner will see it as his sentence being increased to random capital punishment (a daily game of Russian Roulette, where his own officers are as likely to pull the trigger as any Ukrainian), which won't do well for morale..

Comment: I'd guess it's going to be pretty rare, it needs a particular combination of factors: a country that is at war, but also has enough of a functional civil system to have operational prisons, combined with a bureaucracy of conscription and thus some semblance of a rule of law. Compare South Sudan.  I'm sure there are prisoners in the military, but the situation there is far more chaotic than in Russia. That is South Sudan will conscript prisoners, but they don't have a *system* of conscripting prisoners. See https://www.hrw.org/report/2012/06/21/prison-not-me/arbitrary-detention-south-sudan

Comment: Do you only want current day examples (how many countries have military draft today?) or also historic examples say around world war II?

Comment: @quarague: I'd prefer current examples--to stick to the site's focus. I'm sure there's something interesting to be said about ww2 practices though.